# Spring DataSource for Apache Phoenix

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource, apache-phoenix

I am using Spring boot v2.0.4.RELEASE. I am trying to configure jdbc datasource with apache phoenix. I am running a docker image.

```
c6d57621396b        user/phoenix_hbase:4.10.0   "/bin/sh -c /opt/hba…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60000->60000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60010->60010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60020->60020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60030->60030/tcp   docker-hbase
```

I keep getting `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` when running the application.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

The problem is that HikariDataSource cannot bind properties which are in application.properties (my assumption).

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:phoenix:localhost
```

I also tried `jdbc:phoenix:docker-hbase`but nothing changed.

dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile(group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: 'latest.integration')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:latest.integration')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:latest.integration')
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop:2.5.0.RELEASE"
compile(group: 'org.apache.phoenix', name: 'phoenix-core', version:'4.10.0-HBase-1.1') {
        exclude(module: 'slf4j-log4j12')
        exclude(module: 'log4j')
        exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
        exclude(module: 'servlet-api-2.5')
        exclude(module: '*')
    }
```

It only fails if I try to configure with apache phoenix. I also tried my configuration with Postgres and mysql, everything worked as expected.

How can I configure apache phoenix or is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

My conf for using Phoenix as my datasource :

***application.yml*** :

```
# (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring:
    datasource:
        name: phoenix-hadoop
        url: jdbc:phoenix:${zk-nodes}:${port}:/hbase:${principal}@${realm}:${keytab-path}
        driver-class-name: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
        type: com.toto.PhoenixNoPoolingDatasource
```

As it is advised not to use a connection pool with Phoenix Driver, I created this class ***PhoenixNoPoolingDatasource*** to be taken as my datasource type :

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PhoenixNoPoolingDatasource extends SimpleDriverDataSource {
    public PhoenixNoPoolingDatasource() {
    }

    public PhoenixNoPoolingDatasource(Driver driver, String url) {
        super(driver, url);
    }

    public PhoenixNoPoolingDatasource(Driver driver, String url, String username, String password) {
        super(driver, url, username, password);
    }

    public PhoenixNoPoolingDatasource(Driver driver, String url, Properties conProps) {
        super(driver, url, conProps);
    }

    public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName) {
        try {
            Class<?> driverClass = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(driverClassName);
            setDriverClass((Class<? extends Driver>) driverClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load class of driverClassName " + driverClassName, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you may want to look into this dialect https://github.com/jruesga/phoenix-hibernate-dialect as Phoenix Dialect is not ANSI SQL. The main difference being that update and insert statements does not exist. Instead Phoenix uses upsert statements.